# Automatically update packages and delete old versions

Tags: package

I'm a bit compulsive about updating packages for all of my systems, so I find myself running `list-packages` -> `U` -> `x` -> `y` -> `y` pretty much daily to update my packages and delete old versions once the update is complete. How can I automate this process so that at the very least I have to run only one function to update, compile, and delete my packages? Or is there some reason I might not want to do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following is now part of the Paradox package. Just invoke `paradox-upgrade-packages`.

---

This should do it.

```
(defun endless/upgrade ()
  "Upgrade all packages, no questions asked."
  (interactive)
  (save-window-excursion
    (list-packages)
    (package-menu-mark-upgrades)
    (package-menu-execute 'no-query)))
```

Just check which function is called by each of the steps you enumerated, and throw them inside an interactive function. Normally, the `(y or n)` prompts would be an issue, but `package-menu-execute` conveniently takes a `NO-QUERY` argument.

Comment: If all packages are up to date, it will return `No operations specified`.

Answer (score 3):

You can automate this with [Cask](https://github.com/cask/cask). This works for package development, but also for user configuration. The [documentation](http://cask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/usage.html) provides details for setting this up.

Also, [Pallet](https://github.com/rdallasgray/pallet) is useful for keeping your Cask file up-to-date with changes you make in the *Packages* buffer.

Comment: +1 Cask + Pallet are great (but I don't recommend using them on Windows).

Comment: Hmm, that's a problem, because I am on Windows most of the time.

Comment: @rsenna Thanks for the information. I don't run any Windows systems, so I wasn't aware they didn't play nicely.

Comment: In fact you *can* use Cask + Pallet on Windows, with some work. I was able achieve that by using Cygwin, but I remember it was *far* from easy...

Comment: Cask will work fine in Windows once you install Python.  I'm not sure about Pallet since I haven't tested though.  But from looking at the repo it shouldn't depend on anything other than Cask + Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

How about [auto-package-update](https://github.com/rranelli/auto-package-update.el)?

Old versions can be deleted by this customization:

`(setq auto-package-update-delete-old-versions t)`