# Do I have to rename my org-mode load-path folder after every update?

Tags: org-mode, package

I use package manager to update my packages automatically by doing `package-list-packages`, `package-menu-mark-upgrades`, `package-menu-execute`. (I assume this is the easiest way to automatically update all my packages, though I don't really know.)

When I do this, org-mode winds up in a directory with a path like this:

```
~/Dropbox/emacs/prelude/elpa/org-20150511/
```

I use packages that are part of `contrib`, so my .emacs includes these lines:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/Dropbox/emacs/prelude/elpa/org-20150511/lisp" load-path)  
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/Dropbox/emacs/prelude/elpa/org-20150511/contrib" load-path)
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/Dropbox/emacs/prelude/elpa/org-20150511/contrib/lisp" load-path)
```

Since the org directory is named according to the date of the release, this means I have to either: 
1. edit the directory name in the load paths 
2. rename the org folder

Is there a way to get org-mode to find the contrib directories automatically when I upgrade org?

Comment: Another way is to add `orgmode.org/elpa` to `package-archives` as per the instructions [here](http://orgmode.org/elpa.html) and install `org-plus-contrib` from the package manager. That install the regular org files plus the contrib content in a flat folder hierarchy.

Comment: BTW, the last argument you're passing to `add-to-list` does not do what you think does, and you probably don't want it.

Comment: As for the easiest way to upgrade packages: you're doing it right, but [here's a shortcut](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/4052/50).

Answer (score 3):

This solution is specific to how to add the **org contrib** packages to the load path.

You can add `orgmode.org/elpa/` to `package-archives` as per the instructions [here](http://orgmode.org/elpa.html) and install `org-plus-contrib` using the package manager. That will install the regular org files plus the contrib content in a flat folder hierarchy.

The installation instructions from the reference link are repeated here for convenience:

> Add this to your Emacs init file to be able to list the Org mode archives:
>
> `(require 'package)`
>
> `(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)`
>
> Then `M-x list-packages RET` will list both the latest `org` and `org-plus-contrib` packages.
>
> *`org` contains the same set of files that are included in GNU Emacs.*
> *`org-plus-contrib` contains these files plus all contribs files, the ones you find in `contrib/` from the git repo.*

Answer (score 2):

This is a hacky answer but it works (add the code to your `.emacs` file):

```
;; First, define a variable to hold the directory name. It will always
;; be updated whenever there's a new Org version.
;; The important part is this function:
;; (file-name-completion "org-20" "~/Dropbox/emacs/prelude/elpa/")
;; returns:
;; "org-20150511/"
;; or in the future:
;; "org-20250314/"
;; etc.

(setq my-org-from-elpa-dir (expand-file-name (file-name-completion "org-20" "~/Dropbox/emacs/prelude/elpa/") "~/Dropbox/emacs/prelude/elpa/")

;; Finally, add the directories to load-path.
;; (concat my-org-from-elpa-dir "lisp/")
;; returns:
;; "/home/YOU/Dropbox/emacs/prelude/elpa/org-20150511/lisp/"
;; and so on.

(add-to-list 'load-path (concat my-org-from-elpa-dir "lisp/"))
(add-to-list 'load-path (concat my-org-from-elpa-dir "contrib/"))
(add-to-list 'load-path (concat my-org-from-elpa-dir "contrib/lisp/"))
```

Caveats:

This code will be evaluated only at startup so you'll have to restart Emacs after you've upgraded your packages. Or else run `eval-buffer`. Or define a command based on this answer.

In the year 3000 you'll have to change "org-20" for "org-30".

Comment: This looks great. I do have a bunch of other org- packages like `org-bullets` and `org-mac-link` so maybe that's why I'm getting `end of file during parsing`? What if it just looked for something that began with `org-2015`?

Comment: @PeterSalazar Yes! Once I replied & left the computer I thought I left out that very important detail. Just changed my answer to correct that.

Comment: The final sentence is wrong. ;-) That's going to break way before the year 3000.

Comment: @Malabarba Hahah you're absolutely right. Going to leave it there though, it's kind of amusing.